# Store POST in new variable or use $_POST

Tags: php, codeigniter

Usually I call the POST method directly $_POST but if I assign the $_POST variable in new variable will the process speed faster? for example

method 1

```
/* $this->input->post('name') */
$this->db->where("name=".$this->input->post('name'));
$this->db->update(table, $this->input->post('name'));
$this->session->userdata(array("formdata", $this->input->post()));
```

method 2

```
$name = $this->input->post('name');
$this->db->where("name=".$name);
$this->db->update(table, $name);
$this->session->userdata(array("formdata", $this->input->post()));
```

Which method process faster?

Note: Sorry I don't understand how the process work in depth. I've around 30 input. Above query is just an example. There are multiple filter and processing section before sql insert/update. From what I know $_POST is a function and it take more resource than variable/array. I think using variable or array make the processing speed faster.a

Comment: I think the speed difference will be minimal but overall its better to assign post values to variables so you can do further actions with the variables like escape it or something.

Comment: i think $this->db->insert(table, $_POST) is easier and efficient

Comment: WHERE condition in INSERT query ??

Comment: Saty it's just my mistake. I didn't notice that I use insert and where at the same time. I'll change it to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient and better way is

> Generates an update string and runs the query based on the data you
>   supply. You can pass an array or an object to the function. Here is an
>   example using an array:

```
$data = array(
        'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'date' => $this->input->post('date'),
      // ....... and soo ON.........
);

$this->db->where('id', $this->input->post('title'));
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

Read **[updating-data](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#updating-data)**

Comment: I alread use an array I just didn't notice about the processing speed.

Comment: It is just as a update query take additionally All values are escaped automatically producing safer queries. and prevent from sql injection